# whether i can use independent sample t test or not for my sample?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss

Need some urgent help

I am looking for gender difference on one variable

Data is normal

Sample size 83

Males - 67
Females - 16

Which test to run?

Comment: Can you show us some plots, and tell us how you collected the data?

Comment: What @kjetilbhalvorsen is looking for in the plots is evidence of normality. With sample sizes on the smaller side (particularly for females), that assumption could be important. // Regarding how you collected the data, part of the test you want to use is the expectation that observations are independent, and looking at how the data collection occurred gives insight into whether or not that assumption is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Use a two-sample t test. Use the Welch version of the test unless you have good reason to believe
M and F populations have the same variance. Example in R:

```
set.seed(2020)
m = rnorm(67, 68, 4)
f = rnorm(16, 65, 3)

summary(m); length(m);  sd(m)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  55.84   66.52   68.80   68.67   71.49   80.81 
[1] 67       # sample size   
[1] 4.44403  # sample SD
summary(f); length(f); sd(f)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  59.67   62.87   65.03   64.92   66.02   71.94 
[1] 16
[1] 3.218784
```

Sample means are $\bar X_M = 68.67$ and $\bar X_F = 64.92.$ The question is whether
the difference between them is large enough to say that population means also
differ--that is, that the sample means differ *significantly.*

```
boxplot(list(m,f), notch=T, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Notches in the sides of the boxplots are nonparametric confidence intervals
roughly calibrated not to overlap if two population *medians* differ significantly.
They give a clue that we will reject $H_0: \mu_M = \mu_F$ against $H_a: \mu_M \ne \mu_F$
at the 5% level. [Upper boxplot is for F.]

The Welch two-sided two-sample t test for out data is shown below. Notice
that the Welch test has DF somewhat below $n_M+n_F-2 = 67+17-2 = 83-2 = 81$ which would be the DF for a *pooled* two-sample t test.

[The adjustment
in DF occurs because the two samples have different variances. When the two sample sizes differ the t statistics for Welch and pooled two-sample t tests differ. Make sure you have the formula for the Welch test statistic. There is a separate formula for the Welch DF. See your text or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test)] on Welch's test.]

```
t.test(m, f)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  m and f
t = 3.8667, df = 30.336, p-value = 0.0005426
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.771918 5.735038
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 68.67125  64.91777
```

We reject $H_0$ at the 5% level because the P-value $0.00054 < -.05 = 5\%.$